# Make sure all threads are closed or forcibly close a thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I a WPF/C# application that has a psuedo-process of 
Click a button > Start a thread to take a picture from a web cam API > Instantiate the web cam API > API starts a callback thread > Picture is taken > API object is disposed

These steps generally work except for the last portion where the callback thread to the web cam API does not close out. So, in my Task Manager, I invariably end up with a "ghost" process, which shares the same name as my base WPF application. Also, making a second call to the same web cam API (to take a second picture) fails miserably.

So, I'm trying to find a way to make sure that all of my threads from my root application are forcibly closed out at all times. Is there a way to ensure that no threads are left over?

Comment: Pause the debugger and find out what the thread is doing.

Comment: Are the threads explicitly set as background threads?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you set [`IsBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) to true on those threads they will be terminated at shutdown.

Comment: @SLaks: That is true of course, but this is what was asked for here. (To solve the actual problem i would probably recommend setting up a timer so the API call can time out and be interrupted)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a window in your app, set the Application.ShutdownMode to OnMainWindowClose.  That will terminate any running background threads for you when the main window closes.  Programatically you can call Environment.Exit to kill all threads as gracefully as possible (but forcefully if not) and exit the application.

Answer (score 0):

If you see some ghost process besides your main program, it is not a thread problem. You've created other process to perform the operation. Kill it. Your resources will be released. You don't have to worry about threads being running when there is a lot bigger problem - other process hanging on to resources.